ExecutorService - cancel pending tasks
There are multiple questions about waiting for an Java ExecutorService to finish (shutdown() + awaitTermination()) or alternatively cancel them all (shutdownNow()).
I'd like to go for an early exit without interrupting the tasks that have started already. You could also say I'd like to

stop allowing further submissions (shutdown())
cancel all tasks that are still pending
wait for the in-flight tasks to terminate (awaitTermination())

How do I efficiently implement the cancellation?

Note that some ExecutorServices might not even interrupt their threads when calling shutdownNow().

I don't believe the ExecutorService interface provides a way to cancel only submitted-but-not-yet-executing tasks. An implementation might provide a way. For instance, if you know you have a ThreadPoolExecutor then pool.getQueue().clear() might be a viable solution.
